# Basic Javascript algorithm for time implementation (morning, afternoon, etc.)

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have a small JavaScript time detection module that detects what time it is now, like morning, afternoon, evening, or night.

How can I make the following code less redundant? Is my code already clean? It would also be great if I could get some comments on the style of the code. I really want to know what the best coding practices are.

```
var now = new Date(),
    hour = now.getHours();

var morning   = (hour >= 4  && hour <= 11),
    afternoon = (hour >= 12 && hour <= 16),
    evening   = (hour >= 17 && hour <= 20),
    night     = (hour >= 21 || hour <= 3);

if(morning) {

  console.log("It's morning");

} else if(afternoon){

  console.log("It's afternoon");

} else if(evening) {

  console.log("It's evening");

} else if(night) {

  console.log("It's night");

}
```

Comment: 1. You need to detach the logic of how shifts are fixed and decided.
2. You clearly need a structure for referring to each shift in different places. <!--- ---> var shifts = { MORNING = 1, AFTERNOON = 2, EVENING = 3, NIGHT = 4 }; function between(time, start, end) { // As a piece of advice: if you are checking if B is between A and C, do it like A B C... so it's clearer what your are doing return start <= time && time <= end; } function getShift(hour){ if(between(hour, 4, 11)) return shifts.MORNING; if(between(hour, 12, 16)) return shifts.AFTERNOON; if(between(hour, 17, 20)) return shifts.EVEN

Answer (score 2):

The first question has to be: What is the point of this? Do you really want to (only) write the results into the console in a real application?

Other than that, it is a bit pointless to pre-calculate the conditions in variables in this case, because they are only used once and they are exclusive to each other.

Answer (score 1):

You can shorten the `if`- `else` logic by using the ternary operator (i.e. `?:`).

For example:

*condition* ? *true value* : *false value*;

Check [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_conditional_operator_examples.htm).

```
var now  = new Date(),
    hour = now.getHours();

var shift   = "It's ";
    shift  += (hour >= 4  && hour <= 11) ? "morning" : "",
    shift  += (hour >= 12 && hour <= 16) ? "afternoon" : "",
    shift  += (hour >= 17 && hour <= 20) ? "evening" : "",
    shift  += (hour >= 21 || hour <= 3) ?  "night" : "";

    alert(shift);
```

check [here for a demonstration FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/zt7tfqL5/1/).

Comment: You can initialise `shift = "It's "` and later, just add `morning/evening` etc.

Comment: This does multiple unnecessary and costly string concatenations.

Comment: @RoToRa Thanks for your advice, does causes performance issues or something??

Comment: What @RoToRa means by costly concats is, the `shift` variable keeps getting reassigned 4 times for each check and everytime, it is assigned space in memory, concatenated to blank string and the result is pushed back to variable.

Answer (score 1):

Your current code gives you a bunch of booleans, duplicates a lot of code and does unnecessary computations.. You should aim to get the time of day itself rather than a bunch of booleans.

```js
function timeOfDay() {
  let hour = new Date().getHours();
  if (hour >= 4 && hour <= 11) return 'morning';
  if (hour >= 12 && hour <= 16) return 'afternoon';
  if (hour >= 17 && hour <= 20) return 'evening';
  if (hour >= 21 || hour <= 3) return 'night';
}

console.log(`Good ${timeOfDay()}!`);
```

This way you're not evaluating every possible time of day, the function returns on the first match.